# Logging logged-in user ID from JSF session in EJB service layer

Tags: jsf, logging, log4j, ejb

I'm actually using log4j as a logger.  The logger is used in all the application layers (controller, service, dao, etc).  All the layers under the controller layer are also used by a non-JSF app.

When my JSF app is running, how can I get the logged user id in the logger when there is an exception, for instance, in the service layer? The logged-in user is actually stored in the JSF session.

Note : My question is probably related to [How to get the name of the logged in user in JSF service in GlassFish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005006/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-logged-in-user-in-jsf-service-in-glassfish) which seems to conclude that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using homegrown authentication with manually putting the logged-in user in the HTTP session, you'd really have to pass it along yourself as a method argument as the service layer is supposed to be unaware of any frontend specifics such as the HTTP session (i.e., it's forbidden to import/use anything from `javax.faces.*`, `javax.servlet.*`, `javax.ws.*`, etc in the service layer).

When using [container managed authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier.htm#BNCAS) via `j_security_check` or `request.login()`, it's available by [`EJBContext#getCallerPrincipal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getCallerPrincipal()). The `EJBContext` is in turn just injectable via `@Resource`. Here's an usage example in a logging interceptor.

```
@Resource
private EJBContext ejbContext; // You can also inject SessionContext.

@AroundInvoke
public Object log(InvocationContext invocationContext) {
    String username = ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
    // ...
}
```

Note that it's never `null` and defaults to `"anonymous"` when non-logged-in.

Additional advantage of container managed authentication is that you can put security restriction annotations like [`@RolesAllowed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) on service methods. How to use container managed authentication is in turn however a story apart. Start here: [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)